# Best way to aggregate a table with 1.3bn records

Tags: sql, hana

We have a Sap table MARD with a record count of 1.3bn.

Here the data comes at a level of site, article and sloc (lgort)

Sloc being the lowest granular column.

So I want to get a single record for every site,article for which I'm currently using the query

```
(
SELECT WERKS SITE,MATNR ARTICLE ,MIN(LGORT) SLOC
  FROM MARD 
  GROUP BY WERKS,MATNR
  HAVING MIN(LGORT) <>'1000'
);
```

This query takes like 20 mins to execute and consumes 200GB of memory.

Is there any better or faster way to get a single site,article wise row from the table other than aggregating the entire set of data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this version of the query:

```
SELECT m.WERKS as SITE, m.MATNR as ARTICLE, m.LGORT as SLOC
FROM MARD m
WHERE m.LGORD = (SELECT MIN(m2.LGORD)
                 FROM MARD m2
                 WHERE m2.WERKS = m.WERKS AND
                       m2.MATNR = m.MATNR
                ) AND
      m.LGORT <> '1000';
```

Then for performance, you want an index on `(WERKS, MATNR, LGORD)`.

Comment: Also, all fields are already indexed, as these are the primary key.

Comment: @András . . . Because it is not doing an aggregation on the entire data set.

Answer (score 0):

## Take a look at the execution plan

Trace it in ST12, and check the trace file in the Plan Visualiser in Eclipse.
It will tell you, where  the time is spent.